# Not able to replace / with - using pyspark regexp_replace

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I need to  replace / with -.

Example: need to replace 4/24/2022 with 4-24-2022. I want to convert string to date format as YYYY-MM-DD

I tried to use

```
df=df.withColumn("end date", F.regexp_replace(F.col("end date"),"/" ,"-"))
```

and

```
df = df.withColumn('end date', regexp_replace('end date', '/', '-'))
```

able to replace numbers but not '/'.

Comment: are you getting a null after using that? that line works on my setup - spark 3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a string date to date format will require the use of `to_date` (or `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())`).

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('4/24/2022',)]).toDF(['dt_str']). \
    withColumn('dt', func.to_date('dt_str', 'M/d/yyyy')). \
    withColumn('dt_str_hyphens', func.regexp_replace('dt_str', '/', '-')). \
    show()

# +---------+----------+--------------+
# |   dt_str|        dt|dt_str_hyphens|
# +---------+----------+--------------+
# |4/24/2022|2022-04-24|     4-24-2022|
# +---------+----------+--------------+

# root
#  |-- dt_str: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- dt: date (nullable = true)
#  |-- dt_str_hyphens: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: refer [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) for format patterns

Comment: I tried validated_size_df.withColumn("start date", to_date(unix_timestamp("start date", "dd/mm/yyyy").cast("Timestamp"))) but still it is not working

Comment: Tried validated_size_df.withColumn('start date', F.to_date('start date', 'M/d/yyyy')) as well but its not working

Comment: @user19814628 post the code and its error in the question body. what does the date look like in the dataframe?

Comment: I used this ....It worked... to_date_format_df = (
    validated_df
        .withColumn('StartDt', to_date(col('StartDt'), "M/d/yyyy"))
        .withColumn('EndDt', to_date(col('EndDt'), "M/d/yyyy"))
        )

Answer (score 0):

There are two goal that you want to achieve: 1. Convert `/` to `-`. 2. Reorder the format to YYYY-MM-DD format. I think you can use `.to_timestamp()` and `.date_format()` to achieve your goal instead of using regex. Detail please check: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html